# unable see the UI properly in android

Tags: android-layout

Note : for other apps user interface is proper the problem is only for this app
unable to see the ui properly for this app
I never used grid layout before and the ui was fitting well for the other layouts but after I included grid layout the problem with ui has occurred
At first I was unable to run the app so I pressed clean project from build options

[image: UI Screenshot]

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<GridLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_marginTop="150dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="150dp"
    android:background="@drawable/board"
    android:columnCount="3"
    android:rowCount="3"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView12"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="120dp"
        android:layout_row="2"
        android:layout_column="2"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/red"
        tools:layout_width="120dp" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView14"
        android:layout_width="120dp"
        android:layout_height="120dp"
        android:layout_row="1"
        android:layout_column="1"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="30dp"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/red" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView15"
        android:layout_width="120dp"
        android:layout_height="120dp"
        android:layout_row="1"
        android:layout_column="0"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/red" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView16"
        android:layout_width="120dp"
        android:layout_height="120dp"
        android:layout_row="0"
        android:layout_column="2"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/red" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView17"
        android:layout_width="120dp"
        android:layout_height="120dp"
        android:layout_row="0"
        android:layout_column="1"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/red" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView18"
        android:layout_width="120dp"
        android:layout_height="120dp"
        android:layout_row="0"
        android:layout_column="0"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="30dp"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/red" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView19"
        android:layout_width="120dp"
        android:layout_height="120dp"
        android:layout_row="1"
        android:layout_column="2"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/red" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView20"
        android:layout_width="120dp"
        android:layout_height="120dp"
        android:layout_row="2"
        android:layout_column="1"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/red" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView21"
        android:layout_width="120dp"
        android:layout_height="120dp"
        android:layout_row="2"
        android:layout_column="0"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/red" />

</GridLayout>
```

Comment: Do you want to make any list to display images in grid?

Comment: Do you have any static data to display OR Dynamic coming from API?

Comment: @nilesh need to create tic tac toe game using this grid in which red coins are for 1 player and yellow once are for other player